# Taylor Series centered at $\alpha$. Is $\alpha$ arbitrary?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Let's say I have a function $f \in C^{\infty}$ represented by a Taylor Series

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(\alpha)}{n!}(x-\alpha)^n$$

What relevance does $\alpha$ have to $f$? Can we just *choose* any $\alpha$ to be a value where we know how to evaluate $f^{(n)}(\alpha)$?

i.e. Do we just choose a $\alpha$ such that we know the value of the function $f$ and all it's derivatives at that point $\alpha$? If so is $\alpha$ just purely arbitrary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** we need to note we have to be careful about the hypotheses, because $f\in C^\infty(\Bbb R)$ does *not* imply that $f$ *is* represented by its Taylor series. Yes, $\alpha$ is arbitrary, in the sense that if there exists an $\alpha$ that works for every $t$ then any other $\alpha$ also works:

> > **Theorem**. Suppose that $f(t)=\sum\frac{f^{(k)}(\alpha)}{k!}(t-\alpha)^k$ for every $t\in\Bbb R$. Then $f(t)=\sum\frac{f^{(k)}(\beta)}{k!}(t-\beta)^k$ for  every $t,\beta\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that a function is not necessarily represented by its Taylor series, the classic example being $f(x) = e^{-1/x^{2}}, f(0) = 0$ at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. First, you must choose an $\alpha$ such the radius of convergence of the power series is greater than 0. Second, if you are using the power series to compute values of the function for specific values of $x$, then you would want to choose a value of $\alpha$ close to that of $x$ to minimize the number of terms in the series needed to achieve a given accuracy.

Comment: Positive radius of convergence is not nearly enough. Saying the radius of convergence is $r>0$ says just that the series converges for $|x-\alpha|<r$, but it does _not_ say that the sum of the series is actually $f(x)$.

Answer (score -1):

No, It's not arbitray. Because if you choose an alpha and in that alpha, f(alpha) or f'(alpha) or ... Become infinite it won't have meaning. For better understanding try expand f(x)=sqrt(x) and choose alpha=0, you will understand why we can't use any alpha.

Comment: I have no idea what "Because if you choose an alpha and in that alpha, f(alpha) or f'(alpha) or ... Become infinite it won't have meaning." means. The square root function cannot be a counterexample here because it is not infinitely differentiable.